# Retrieving the challenge questions present in /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection location

Tags: wso2-identity-server

In wso2 IS version 6.0, I want to use is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/# rest API's for retrieving the questions stored in /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection. Will these rest API's work for retrieving those questions or else do we have any other rest API's for retrieving those questions?

Answer (score 0):

- There is no REST API to manage the questions stored in
  `/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection`
- `/_system/config/identity/questionCollection` is the expected location to have challenge questions.

Refer to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73997306/10055162 for more details